# Add json object in first element of json

Tags: java

I have the following input json:

```
[{
    "DT": "2021-06-03 09:15:00",
    "High": 1509.75,
    "Low": 1488
  },
  {
    "DT": "2021-06-03 09:45:00",
    "High": 1514,
    "Low": 1511
  },
  ...]
```

I fetched the following objects by passing the value of "DT" from above input from database

```
object1 = [{"desc":"abc"}]
object2 = [{"desc":"xzy"}]
```

Now, I need to add object1 and object2 value into the first 1st object from the input whose "DT" value got matched

```
[{
    "DT": "2021-06-03 09:15:00",
    "High": 1509.75,
    "Low": 1488,
    "data": [
      {
        "desc": "abc"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "DT": "2021-06-03 09:45:00",
    "High": 1514,
    "Low": 1511
  },
  ...]
```

How to do it?

Comment: Which library do you use to process your JSON objects ?

Comment: org.json library

Comment: can you share code which you tried for this operation ?

Answer (score 0):

public void getData() {

```
    String response = "";
    String corpMemKey = "";
    String corpRes = "";
    Map<String, List<JSONObject>> eventDtlsMap = new HashMap<String, List<JSONObject>>();

    try {

        Map<String, String> valueDtlsMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        valueDtlsMap.put("abc_2021-06-03", "[{\"desc\":\"abc\"}]");
        valueDtlsMap.put("abc_2021-06-07", "[{\"desc\":\"xzy\"}]");

        ArrayList<String> companyList = new ArrayList<String>();
        companyList.add("abc");

        String res = "[{\"DT\":\"2021-06-03 09:15:00\",\"High\":1509.75,\"Low\":1488},{\"DT\":\"2021-06-03 09:45:00\",\"High\":1514,\"Low\":1511},{\"DT\":\"2021-06-03 10:15:00\",\"High\":1514.25,\"Low\":1512.75},{\"DT\":\"2021-06-03 10:45:00\",\"High\":1512.1,\"Low\":1509.8},{\"DT\":\"2021-06-04 09:15:00\",\"High\":1519.75,\"Low\":1514.1},{\"DT\":\"2021-06-04 09:45:00\",\"High\":1516.2,\"Low\":1514.6},{\"DT\":\"2021-06-04 10:15:00\",\"High\":1517.95,\"Low\":1515.6},{\"DT\":\"2021-06-04 10:45:00\",\"High\":1512.75,\"Low\":1507.55},{\"DT\":\"2021-06-07 09:15:00\",\"High\":1510.85,\"Low\":1502.25},{\"DT\":\"2021-06-07 09:45:00\",\"High\":1500.25,\"Low\":1499.3},{\"DT\":\"2021-06-07 10:15:00\",\"High\":1503.45,\"Low\":1502},{\"DT\":\"2021-06-08 09:30:00\",\"High\":1496.4,\"Low\":1486.25},{\"DT\":\"2021-06-08 10:00:00\",\"High\":1490,\"Low\":1486},{\"DT\":\"2021-06-08 10:30:00\",\"High\":1488.4,\"Low\":1484.1}]";
        JSONArray companyJsonArr = new JSONArray(res);

        if (companyList.size() > 0) {
            for (String company : companyList) {

                if (companyJsonArr.length() > 0) {

                    JSONObject respJson = new JSONObject();
                    for (int i = 0; i < companyJsonArr.length(); i++) {
                        respJson = companyJsonArr.getJSONObject(i);
                        String date = respJson.getString("DT");
                        String converDate = convertDate(date);
                        corpMemKey = company + "_" + converDate;
                        if (valueDtlsMap.get(corpMemKey) != null) {
                            eventDtlsMap.computeIfAbsent(corpMemKey, k -> new ArrayList<>());
                            eventDtlsMap.get(corpMemKey).add(respJson);
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println("eventDtlsMap : " + eventDtlsMap);
                    if (eventDtlsMap.size() > 0) {
                        for (Entry<String, List<JSONObject>> e : eventDtlsMap.entrySet()) {
                            String keyFromMap = e.getKey();
                            Object valueFromMap = eventDtlsMap.get(keyFromMap);
                            JSONArray respArr = new JSONArray(valueFromMap.toString().trim());
                            System.out.println("respArr : " + respArr);
                            respJson = respArr.getJSONObject(0);
                            if (valueDtlsMap.get(keyFromMap) != null) {
                                corpRes = (String) valueDtlsMap.get(keyFromMap);
                                respJson.put("data", new JSONArray(corpRes.trim()));
                                companyJsonArr.put(respJson);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    response = companyJsonArr.toString().trim();
                    System.out.println("response : " + response);
                }
                if (companyJsonArr != null) {
                    companyJsonArr = null;
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public static String convertDate(String date) {

    String formattedDate = "";

    try {
        SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:00");
        SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date parsedDate = inputFormat.parse(date);
        formattedDate = outputFormat.format(parsedDate);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Exception for convertDate() :" + ex);
    }
    return formattedDate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am getting following response :

```
[
  {
    "DT": "2021-06-03 09:15:00",
    "High": 1509.75,
    "Low": 1488
  },
  {
    "DT": "2021-06-03 09:45:00",
    "High": 1514,
    "Low": 1511
  },
  {
    "DT": "2021-06-03 10:15:00",
    "High": 1514.25,
    "Low": 1512.75
  },
  {
    "DT": "2021-06-03 10:45:00",
    "High": 1512.1,
    "Low": 1509.8
  },
  {
    "DT": "2021-06-04 09:15:00",
    "High": 1519.75,
    "Low": 1514.1
  },
  {
    "DT": "2021-06-04 09:45:00",
    "High": 1516.2,
    "Low": 1514.6
  },
  {
    "DT": "2021-06-04 10:15:00",
    "High": 1517.95,
    "Low": 1515.6
  },
  {
    "DT": "2021-06-04 10:45:00",
    "High": 1512.75,
    "Low": 1507.55
  },
  {
    "DT": "2021-06-07 09:15:00",
    "High": 1510.85,
    "Low": 1502.25
  },
  {
    "DT": "2021-06-07 09:45:00",
    "High": 1500.25,
    "Low": 1499.3
  },
  {
    "DT": "2021-06-07 10:15:00",
    "High": 1503.45,
    "Low": 1502
  },
  {
    "DT": "2021-06-08 09:30:00",
    "High": 1496.4,
    "Low": 1486.25
  },
  {
    "DT": "2021-06-08 10:00:00",
    "High": 1490,
    "Low": 1486
  },
  {
    "DT": "2021-06-08 10:30:00",
    "High": 1488.4,
    "Low": 1484.1
  },
  {
    "DT": "2021-06-03 09:15:00",
    "High": 1509.75,
    "data": [
      {
        "desc": "abc"
      }
    ],
    "Low": 1488
  },
  {
    "DT": "2021-06-07 09:15:00",
    "High": 1510.85,
    "data": [
      {
        "desc": "xzy"
      }
    ],
    "Low": 1502.25
  }
]
```

but I don't want duplicate of `"DT":"2021-06-03 09:15:00"` and `"DT":"2021-06-07 09:15:00"` objects

Answer (score 0):

**A Javascript Version**

```js
var input = [{"DT":"2021-06-03 09:15:00","High":1509.75,"Low":1488},{"DT":"2021-06-03:09:45:00","High":1514,"Low":1511},{"DT":"2021-06-03:10:15:00","High":1514.25,"Low":1512.75},{"DT":"2021-06-03:10:45:00","High":1512.1,"Low":1509.8},{"DT":"2021-06-04:09:15:00","High":1519.75,"Low":1514.1},{"DT":"2021-06-04:09:45:00","High":1516.2,"Low":1514.6},{"DT":"2021-06-04:10:15:00","High":1517.95,"Low":1515.6},{"DT":"2021-06-04:10:45:00","High":1512.75,"Low":1507.55},{"DT":"2021-06-07:09:15:00","High":1510.85,"Low":1502.25},{"DT":"2021-06-07:09:45:00","High":1500.25,"Low":1499.3},{"DT":"2021-06-07:10:15:00","High":1503.45,"Low":1502},{"DT":"2021-06-08:09:30:00","High":1496.4,"Low":1486.25},{"DT":"2021-06-08:10:00:00","High":1490,"Low":1486},{"DT":"2021-06-08:10:30:00","High":1488.4,"Low":1484.1}];
var object1 = [{"desc":"abc"}];
var object2 = [{"desc":"xzy"}];
input.forEach(function(item, index){
  if(item.DT === "2021-06-03 09:15:00"){
    item.data = [{"desc":"abc"}];
    document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(item);
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>

<h2>Handle a JSON array easily! </h2>


<p id="show"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

---

**Update - Java Version (easy to go)**

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Main {

    private static final String INPUT = "[{\"DT\":\"2021-06-03 09:15:00\",\"High\":1509.75,\"Low\":1488},{\"DT\":\"2021-06-03 09:45:00\",\"High\":1514,\"Low\":1511},{\"DT\":\"2021-06-03 10:15:00\",\"High\":1514.25,\"Low\":1512.75},{\"DT\":\"2021-06-03 10:45:00\",\"High\":1512.1,\"Low\":1509.8},{\"DT\":\"2021-06-04 09:15:00\",\"High\":1519.75,\"Low\":1514.1},{\"DT\":\"2021-06-04 09:45:00\",\"High\":1516.2,\"Low\":1514.6},{\"DT\":\"2021-06-04 10:15:00\",\"High\":1517.95,\"Low\":1515.6},{\"DT\":\"2021-06-04 10:45:00\",\"High\":1512.75,\"Low\":1507.55},{\"DT\":\"2021-06-07 09:15:00\",\"High\":1510.85,\"Low\":1502.25},{\"DT\":\"2021-06-07 09:45:00\",\"High\":1500.25,\"Low\":1499.3},{\"DT\":\"2021-06-07 10:15:00\",\"High\":1503.45,\"Low\":1502},{\"DT\":\"2021-06-08 09:30:00\",\"High\":1496.4,\"Low\":1486.25},{\"DT\":\"2021-06-08 10:00:00\",\"High\":1490,\"Low\":1486},{\"DT\":\"2021-06-08 10:30:00\",\"High\":1488.4,\"Low\":1484.1}]";
    private static JSONObject[] DESCRIPTIONS = new JSONObject[]{
            (new JSONObject()).put("desc", "abc"),
            (new JSONObject()).put("desc", "xyz")
    };
    private static final String DESCRIPTION_KEY = "data";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JSONArray inputJSONArray;
        try {
            inputJSONArray = new JSONArray(INPUT);

            for (int i = 0; i < inputJSONArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject currJSONObj = inputJSONArray.getJSONObject(i);
                if(currJSONObj.get("DT").equals("2021-06-03 09:15:00")){
                    currJSONObj.put(DESCRIPTION_KEY, DESCRIPTIONS[0]);
                    System.out.println(currJSONObj);
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException jex){
            throw new JSONException("Error occured while instantiating the " + JSONArray.class.getName() +
                    " object from given " + String.class.getName(), jex);
        }
    } 
}
```

**The Result is the following:**

**{"DT":"2021-06-03 09:15:00","High":1509.75,"data":{"desc":"abc"},"Low":1488}**

---

**Additional Java Version - Answer**

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Main {

    private static final String INPUT = "[{\"DT\":\"2021-06-03 09:15:00\",\"High\":1509.75,\"Low\":1488},{\"DT\":\"2021-06-03 09:45:00\",\"High\":1514,\"Low\":1511},{\"DT\":\"2021-06-03 10:15:00\",\"High\":1514.25,\"Low\":1512.75},{\"DT\":\"2021-06-03 10:45:00\",\"High\":1512.1,\"Low\":1509.8},{\"DT\":\"2021-06-04 09:15:00\",\"High\":1519.75,\"Low\":1514.1},{\"DT\":\"2021-06-04 09:45:00\",\"High\":1516.2,\"Low\":1514.6},{\"DT\":\"2021-06-04 10:15:00\",\"High\":1517.95,\"Low\":1515.6},{\"DT\":\"2021-06-04 10:45:00\",\"High\":1512.75,\"Low\":1507.55},{\"DT\":\"2021-06-07 09:15:00\",\"High\":1510.85,\"Low\":1502.25},{\"DT\":\"2021-06-07 09:45:00\",\"High\":1500.25,\"Low\":1499.3},{\"DT\":\"2021-06-07 10:15:00\",\"High\":1503.45,\"Low\":1502},{\"DT\":\"2021-06-08 09:30:00\",\"High\":1496.4,\"Low\":1486.25},{\"DT\":\"2021-06-08 10:00:00\",\"High\":1490,\"Low\":1486},{\"DT\":\"2021-06-08 10:30:00\",\"High\":1488.4,\"Low\":1484.1}]";
    private static JSONObject[] DESCRIPTIONS = new JSONObject[]{
            (new JSONObject()).put("desc", "abc"),
            (new JSONObject()).put("desc", "xyz")
    };
    private static final String DESCRIPTION_KEY = "data";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JSONArray inputJSONArray;
        try {
            inputJSONArray = new JSONArray(INPUT);

            for (int i = 0; i < inputJSONArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject currJSONObj = inputJSONArray.getJSONObject(i);
                if(currJSONObj.get("DT").equals("2021-06-03 09:15:00")){
                    JSONArray currData = new JSONArray("[" + DESCRIPTIONS[0].toString() + "]");
                    currJSONObj.put(DESCRIPTION_KEY, currData);
                    inputJSONArray.put(i, currJSONObj);
                    System.out.println(currJSONObj);
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException jex){
            throw new JSONException("Error occured while instantiating the " + JSONArray.class.getName() +
                    " object from given " + String.class.getName(), jex);
        }
    }
}
```

**{"DT":"2021-06-03 09:15:00","High":1509.75,"data":[{"desc":"abc"}],"Low":1488}**

Hopefully, this will help you out, accept the answer if it matches your goal exactly!

*PS: I stringified the JSON object, so it can be displayed in Javascript Version.*

Comment: i want this in java code. and "DT" is dynamic

Comment: Yes i understand, but you are free to use it as kind of meta instance :). I will post the Java Version in a Main class soon...

Comment: no this is not working. "DT" is dynamic it might be "2021-06-03 09:13:00" or "2021-06-04 10:15:00"